# Refreshing a webpage using Androidhelper in Qpython3

Tags: android, python-3.x, qpython3

```
import androidhelper 
a="https://www.bing.com/search?q=a&PC=SAADAND&form=LWS001&ssp=1&cc=IN&setlang=en-gb&darkschemeovr=1&safesearch=moderate"
androidhelper.Android().startActivity("android.intent.action.VIEW", a)
```

This my code so far and it's opening the browser without any problems.. however I want to refresh the webpage with new links each time one gets loaded.. using for loop.. ex-

```
import androidhelper 
a=['a','b','c','d']
For i in a:
   Url="https://www.bing.com/searchq="+i+"&PC=
SAADAND&form=LWS001&ssp=1&cc=IN&setlang=en-gb&darkschemeovr=1&safesearch=moderate"
   androidhelper.Android().startActivity("
android.intent.action.VIEW", url)
```

I'm expecting a qpython program or more like a script that will open my bing browser and continuously search for the url I provide without wasting any time. Upon completion of the operation it'll close the browser as well.